# moment-isocalendar not working

Tags: node.js, date, datetime, momentjs

According to their documentation, all one needs to do is require the `moment-isocalendar` module.

This does not work:

```
var m = require("moment");
var i = require("moment-isocalendar");
m().isocalendar();
```

It throws

```
TypeError: Object Tue Aug 13 2013 18:20:36 GMT+0300 has no method 'isocalendar'
    at repl:1:6
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

I looked at the module (all were installed with `npm`), and it requires the "moment" and monkey-patches it. I tried requiring the `moment-isocalendar` before the `moment` module, but got the same result. The `moment-isocalendar` is an empty object after the monkey-patch `{}`.

Has anyone used a momentjs plugin in nodejs before? Any ideas how to make this work?

**Later edit**

It works in nodejs v0.10.12, it doesn't work in nodejs v0.10.15. I added an answer.

**Later edit**

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 with 3.8.0-26-generic kernel, and the nodejs is installed via package manager from ppa:chris-lea/node.js

Comment: This works for me in v0.10.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moment-isocalendar` is a plugin, not part of the main moment.js library.  My guess is that they didn't update it for the last moment.js release, but I have not verified this.

You should raise an issue here: https://github.com/fusionbox/moment-isocalendar

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, the answer is simple: it is not working. It was relying on an older nodejs feature (bug) where you could monkey-patch the in-memory modules after their first `require`, which apparently doesn't work anymore (worked in 0.10.12, doesn't work in 0.10.15).

If anyone gets the module as-is working i'll change the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I haven't managed to make it work. Just the three lines of code in my question, they work on my machine in 0.10.12 and throw the error in 0.10.15 :/